# get values from controller of the clicked element on the next page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on an ecommerce portal in angularjs where i have multiple products in controller like this

```
$scope.products = [
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 14, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 11, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 10, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 9, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 8, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 13, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 12, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 7, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 6, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 3, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 2, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 1, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 5, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 4, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 14, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 11, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 10, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 9, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 8, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 13, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 12, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 7, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 6, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 3, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 2, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 1, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 5, link: '#products_detail'},
    {imgLink: 'product1.jpg', name: 'Wingtip Congnac Oxford', price: 4, link: '#products_detail'},
];
```

I am getting the product in view with ng-repeat and its working fine. Here is the URL for the product page http://trendnyou.com/#/products

Now i want to extend this and when i click on **buy now** on any button it opens a detail page throught **`routeprovider`** where i need to fetch the value from the same controller but of the clicked product only. Here is the URL for details page http://trendnyou.com/#/products_detail

Right now this is a dummy page with same data no matter on what product you click i want to show the data of the clicked product only.

Comment: do you use `ui-router`?

Comment: no in this application i am using `routeProvider` -> `ng-view`

Comment: can you expose your controllers ?

Comment: you can pass parameter in url and get using $routeParams. or u can use service for this

Comment: @SunilGarg you can say thats an another solution which is good but there can be one more case if user will remove the parameter and then load the url then it will show incomplete page keeping this in mind used localstorage so if user will reload the page nothing will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount a simplest way which is working fine for me

Make a function in which store the index of the clicked element like this

```
$scope.storeSelectedProduct = function(){
    localStorage.selectedProduct = this.$index;
}
```

and running this function on `ng-click` of the product and storing index to localstorage so that value will not vanished on the page reload.

Now when page change i am initialising a function with `ng-init` to get the value to local variable

```
$scope.getSelectedProduct = function(){
    $scope.selectedProduct = localStorage.getItem('selectedProduct');
}
```

now i left with task showing the details of clicked element only for that i am using `ng-repeat` with slice and getting the values from the same controller from which i am getting values in product listing page

```
ng-repeat="product in products.slice('selectedProduct','selectedProduct+1')"
```

With this i am getting all the values from the same controller but from the clicked element only instead storing all the values in localstorage i am just storing the index.

Answer (score 1):

Write ng-click event for the link you click and store the specifc product detail into a localstorage and then redirect to the respective location. In products_detail controller you can read again from localstorage and render it.

```
    function storeSelectedProduct(){
        localStorage.setItem('selectedProduct',obj);        
    }

     $routeProvider.when("/products_detail", {
            controller: "productdetailcontroller",
            templateUrl: "detail.html",
            resolve: {
                "selectedProduct": function () {
                   return localStorage.getItem('selectedProduct');   
                }
            }
        });
app.controller("productdetailcontroller", function ($scope, selectedProduct)   {
            $scope.selectedProduct = selectedProduct;
        });
```

Now you can read the selected product from current scope.

Comment: i am already using `routepriovider` do you think i should use `$location.path` along?

Comment: could you please explain how `obj` is storing the controller values here??

Comment: You should require some identifier in the Product array to identify the product. Inside storeSelectedProduct method you may need to query those array and then get it to obj.